# Akaike information criterion. AICs analysis ( sample size =5, No of parameters (not counting the error variance) = 3), in result AICc = infinite.

Tags: regression, correlation, aic

Could you please recommend another formula for AIC correction for small sample size (n/k < 40)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc the "AIC with correction" is used for small sample sizes, is this what you are using?

Comment: You shouldn't do anything that has 5 observations and 3 variables.  You will surely be overfitting the data. The infinite AICc is a warning.  You shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: Why is AIC infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other formulas for AIC.  There are other fit statistics, some of them variations on AIC, such as AICc, but that starts with AIC which will be infinite (as you state) and then adds to it:

$$AICc = AIC + \frac{2k^2 + 2k}{n - k - 1} $$

where n is sample size and k is the number of parameters.

There is also BIC:

$$BIC = ln(n)k - 2*ln{\hat{L}}$$

But there is a more basic problem: You are modeling 5 cases with 3 parameters.  You shouldn't do that. You will be overfitting your data. You need a lot more data or a simpler model.

Comment: Isn’t the purpose of AIC etc to penalise overfitting? Seems odd to say it shouldn’t be used in cases for which overfitting is suspected

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose. And, in fact, that's what it is doing. It is saying THERE IS OVERFITTING.  It is shouting that. So, I didn't say "don't use it" I said "listen to it".

Comment: Right, ok, calculate it and listen to it